# timer_create for multiple threads in C++

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, signals

Multiple threads call a method and setup a timer with timer_create and 
timer_settime. I am trying to pass the thread id in

> sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &info;

however when the handler is called it comes with a different thread id (probably the main function's id) and my cancel method is not called.

```
        timer_t timerid;
        struct sigevent sev;
        struct itimerspec its;
        long long freq_nanosecs;
        sigset_t mask;
        struct sigaction sa; 

        sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
        sa.sa_sigaction = &handler;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

        sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
        sev.sigev_signo = SIGUSR1;
        sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &info;
        timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerid);
        /* Start the timer */

        its.it_value.tv_sec = 3;
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
        its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
        its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;

        timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL);
```

Now the handler is

```
        Info *inc;
        inc = (Info *)si->si_value.sival_ptr;

        std::thread::id thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();

        if(inc->thread_id != thread_id){
                LOG << "This thread is not blocking";
        } else {
                printf("Caught signal %d from timer\n", sig);

                cancel(...);
        }
```

My problem is that I cannot correctly identify a proper way to identify to call the cancel method based on a unique value that comes from the calling thread.

Any suggestion

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to use `SIGEV_THREAD_ID` (which targets the signal at a specific thread) rather than `SIGEV_SIGNAL` (which sends the signal to the process)?

Comment: If that is the code of your signal handler, then the functions you call there are not async-signal safe, i.e. that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin this is the code of the signal handler indeed. How should I use it in order to be async signal safe?

Comment: @Hasturkun I modified the code using SIGEV_THREAD_ID and the program crashed.

Comment: You should not use that code in the signal handler at all. Use unix [self-pipe](https://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) trick to avoid doing anything in signal handlers.

Comment: How did you change the code? Are you setting `sigev_notify_thread_id` with the value returned from `gettid()` as suggested by [the `timer_create()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)?

Comment: What is your high-level problem?

Comment: @Hasturkun sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID; and sev._sigev_un._tid = syscall(__NR_gettid); the hanldler was never called

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin my higher-level problem is that I want to send an abort to my database if a connection takes more than 30 secs

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin what is the problem with the handler? Which part is not async-signal safe?

Comment: @cateof None of the functions the signal handler calls are async-signal safe. Find a list of async-signal safe functions: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blocking `connect` or `read`/`recv`/`recvmsg`/`recvfrom` return `EINTR` when interrupted by a signal and no `SA_RESTART` is used for that signal. This was the main intention behind `alarm` syscall, however, it was invented before multi-threading, so it sends the signal to the process rather than a specific thread.

To break from a blocking socket `connect` call set a timer that sends a signal to the particular thread using `SIGEV_THREAD_ID`. Send the signal handler to 
`SIG_IGN` and make sure `SA_RESTART` is not used for that signal.

Comment: I cannot manipulate the socket, my code does not have access there.

Comment: However, I have a connection pointer that when a timer elapses I can call something like cancel(connection_ptr)

Comment: @cateof I would try sending a signal to that thread blocked in `connect` and see what happens. Run under `strace`.